# Hangfire recurring job daily on specific time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, background-process, hangfire, recurring

I am trying to run hangfire recurring job daily on 9.00 AM. Here is what I want to do-

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MyMethod(), "* 9 * * *");
```

Where should I put this line of code?

Sorry if this is a foolish question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are using `.Net Core`, where you can find the file `startup.cs`. In that you can find a `Configure()` method. Inside the method you can use that piece of line right after `app.UseHangfireDashboard()` and `app.UseHangfireServer()` which is for configuring hangfire dashboard and this is optional. Don't forget to **Register Hangfire Services** in `ConfigureServices()` method which can be found in the `startup.cs` itself.

You can **Register Hangfire Services** inside `ConfigureServices()` in **Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {    
    /*
    other services
    */

    services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage("YOUR_HangfireServerConnectionString"));

    /*
    services.AddMvc()
    */
    }
```

You can **Set Hangfire Cron** inside `Configure()` in **Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();  
    app.UseHangfireServer();
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MyMethod(), "* 9 * * *");
}
```

for more refer the [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/schedule-background-jobs-using-hangfire-in-asp-net-core/)

**UPDATE**

The cron expression `* 9 * * *` denotes that the job will fires every minutes after 9 (24 hour format) of <strike>system time</strike> UTC time.

For creating a recurring job at 9.00 AM Daily, the expression should be `0 9 * * *` refer here [cron expressions](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_*_*_*)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I am not using .net core.

Comment: For your information, If you don't want the same job running from different instances, You should give a unique identifier while adding the cron like this `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("YOUR_UNIQUE_STRING",() => MyMethod(), "* 9 * * *");`

Comment: @s.k.paul  Don't forget in Hangfire to daily schedule. Works like this:
 
`RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => MyMethod(), Cron.Daily(9,0));`

Comment: @WladimirTeixeira I have updated the answer with cron expression. That was an unnoticed mistake i copied from the question which makes a remarkable impact on the server.

Answer (score 3):

In asp.net, you can add Microsoft.Owin Middleware and OwinStartup to your project via this [nugetpackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) and then use the startup.cs to setup hangfire. We always use the Configuration method of Startup.cs file for the hangfire recurring jobs:

```
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) 
            {
                app.UseHangfireDashboard();
                app.UseHangfireServer();
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(19872.ToString(),() => MyMethod(), Cron.Daily(9, 0));
            }
```

Comment: Just hint for 2023, this is obsolete, use: `builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();`

Answer (score 2):

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => homeCtrl.SendEmail(), Cron.Daily(hour,minute), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

without TimeZoneInfo.Local it will use default UTC time. You have to use TimeZoneInfo.Local always to
get your exact time.

```
        var corn = Cron.Daily();    // "0 0 * * *"  Every night at 12:00 AM

        var corn1 = Cron.Daily(11, 30);   // "30 11 * * *"

        var corn2 = Cron.Daily(12);   // "0 12 * * *"

        var corn3 = Cron.Daily(23,55);  // "55 23 * * *"
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a web api endpoint for creating jobs. I always give the recurring job a unique identifier like a guid. That way, if i need to edit the recurring jobs chron expression and can update it via my web api endpoint.

So in the web api i have :-

```
[HttpPost]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("daily")]
public IActionResult AddOrUpdateDailyReportJob([FromBody]JobOptions options)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var result = _clientReportJobCreator.AddOrUpdateDailyClientReport(options.JobId, options.ChronExpression);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

And a service method like this that adds or updates an existing recurring job.

```
 public JobCreationResult AddOrUpdateDailyClientReport(string jobId, string chronExpression)
        {
            try
            {
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobId, () => _clientDailyReportService.Run(), chronExpression);

                var result = new JobCreationResult
                {
                    JobId = jobId,
                    Success = true
                };

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var result = new JobCreationResult
                {
                    JobId = jobId,
                    Success = false,
                    Errors = new List<string>()
                    {
                        $"{ex.Message}"
                    }
                };

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: U dont show what your job options is here? Or in fact what is _clientReportJobCreator leaves the code incomplete for anyone else please fix this.